# I have an error ORA-01422 in ORACLE with my trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I created a trigger to not allow the same user to be inserted with the same chat two or more times, but I missed this error:

```
exact fetch returns more than one requested number of rows tips
```

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OCEX_VERIFICAR_CHARLA
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ID_CHARLA, CIP_PER ON OCEX_CHARLA_PERSONAL_PNP
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
 cip varchar2(8);
 charla number(38);
BEGIN
select cip_per into cip from OCEX_CHARLA_PERSONAL_PNP;

select id_charla into charla from OCEX_CHARLA_PERSONAL_PNP;

if (cip = :new.cip_per and charla = :new.id_charla) then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20018,'YOU CAN'T INSERT TO DUPLICATE DATA.');
end if;
END;
```

Some idea of why this error jumps and that should change in trigger, thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a unique constraint?

Comment: @AlexPoole Because the user can register in another "charla".

Comment: Alex is right. You should definitely be using a *UNIQUE CONSTRAINT* for this requirement.The problem with your select queries in the trigger is that they don't have a where clause, hence multiple rows are returned into a single scalar variable, which causes the error. I can tell you how to resolve  that, but it won't  be a right solution for this case as Trigger is unnecessary.

Comment: Hi @KaushikNayak the relationship between id_charla and cip_per is from many to many, that is why I do not contemplate putting the fields unique_straight and cip_per as unique constraint

Comment: +1 for uniqueness. A simple way would be to `create index ui1_per_cha on ocex_charla_personal_pnp (id_charla, cip_per)`; you don't have to create it on a single column - no problem in spreading through two (or more) of them.

Comment: loool maybe was because I'm learning about Oracle and never heard of *unique constraint** Thanks everyone, my problem was solved. :)